# Is it possible to get the raw text of a webpage post JS in python

Tags: python

I've tried using:

```
html = requests.get(my_website).text
soup = BeautifulSoup(html)
print soup.get_text()
```

But the issue that I run into is that Javascript isn't getting rendered.

Comment: What do you mean not getting rendered? You want to get the actual javascript code? Is it loaded in a separate .js file?

Comment: @MKYung oh no, for example if the article is loaded via Ajax, that would not get loaded for obvious reasons as it's a simple get request for the raw html.

Comment: Beautiful Soup does not run javascript. To get it running you need a headless browser like @Rahul mentioned

Answer (score 1, accepted):

JavaScript is not automatically rendered using BeautifulSoup. You may want to try tools like `Selenium`, `Mechanize`, `PhantomJs` with BeautifulSoup to render JavaScript. [Dryscrape](https://github.com/niklasb/dryscrape) is also a good tool to look into.

Comment: This, but the term for a lot of these tools is "headless browser." BeautifulSoul is just an HTML parser (which is part of a browser).